# How to send registration confirmation email - php/ swift?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am workng on a web application using php and sql server. It's a registration form, I want to add an email confirmation to it. It's just a simple form, the user should receive an email confirmation after submitting the form.

I am trying doing it in swift, the form is getting submitted and the database gets updated too. Just the email confirmation doesn't work.

Can you please check the code or suggest any alternative to it?

```
require_once './functions/queries.php';
<div class="container" >


            <form id="Form" action="functions/processEmail.php" method="post" >
                <div id="FormResult" class="hide" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <div id="resultFormContent"></div>
                </div>

                    <div class="form-row">

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="fName">First Name </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="mName">Middle Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mName" name="mName" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="lName">Last Name </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" name="lName" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="hEthnicity">Hispanic Ethnicity</label>
                        <Select name="hEthnicity" class="form-control" id="hEthnicity"  required>
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            <option value="Hispanic">Hispanic</option>
                            <option value="Not Hispanic">Not Hispanic</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="race">Race</label>
                        <select class="form-control"  id="race" name="race[]" multiple="multiple" required>
                            <option value="Black/African American">Black/African American</option>
                            <option value="White/Caucasian">White/Caucasian</option>
                            <option value="Asian">Asian</option>
                            <option value="American Indian or Alaskan Native">American Indian or Alaskan Native</option>
                            <option value="Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


                   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender" required>
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            <option value="Prefer not to answer">Prefer not to answer</option>
                        </select>
                   </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="Age">Age</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" maxlength="2" required></input>
                    </div>


                        <br>
                    <div class="form-row">     
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="education">Education level</label>
                        <Select name="education" class="form-control" id="education" required>
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            <option value="HS Freshman">HS Freshman</option>
                            <option value="HS Sophomore">HS Sophomore</option>
                            <option value="HS Junior">HS Junior</option>
                            <option value="HS Senior">HS Senior</option>
                            <option value="College undergraduate">College undergraduate</option>
                            <option value="Post-Baccalaureate">Post-Baccalaureate</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="gpa">GPA</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gpa" name="gpa" maxlength="5" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>       
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="hPhone">Home Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hPhone" name="hPhone" maxlength="10" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="cPhone">Cell Phone </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cPhone"  name="cPhone" maxlength="10" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="pEmail">Preferred Email </label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="pEmail" name="pEmail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="aEmail">Alternate Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="aEmail" name="aEmail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="inputAddress">Mailing Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="inputCity" required>
                        </div>
</div>
```

db-connect.php

```
<?php

class DB{
    protected static $db;
    const SERVER = "xxx";
    const SCHEMA = "premed";
    const USER = "xxxx";
    const PASS =  "xxx";        
    /*
     * Sets up the database connection
     * @return the database instance
     */
    public static function databaseConnection(){
        if(!self::$db){
            try {

                $databse = "sqlsrv:server=" . self::SERVER . ";Database=" . self::SCHEMA;
                self::$db = new PDO($databse, DB::USER, DB::PASS);  
                self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die("Error " . $e->getMessage());
            }   
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
?>
```

register.php

```
require_once("db-connect.php");
class Queries{




public static function addStudent($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race, $hEthnicity, $gender,$age,   $education, $gpa, $hPhone, $cPhone, $pEmail, $aEmail, $inputAddress, $inputCity)
                {
        $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.info ( FName,LName, MidInitial, Race, Ethnicity, Gender, Age, SchoolYear, Gpa, HPhone, CPhone, PEmail, AEmail, MailAddress, MailCity) 
                VALUES 
                ( :fName,:lName, :mName, :race, :hEthnicity, :gender,:age, :education, :gpa, :hPhone, :cPhone, :pEmail, :aEmail, :inputAddress, :inputCity)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);   
        $stmt->bindParam(':fName', $fName);
                $stmt->bindParam(':lName', $lName);
                $stmt->bindParam(':mName', $mName);
                $stmt->bindParam(':race', $race);
                $stmt->bindParam(':hEthnicity', $hEthnicity);
               $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
               $stmt->bindParam(':age', $age);
                $stmt->bindParam(':education', $education);
                $stmt->bindParam(':gpa', $gpa);
                $stmt->bindParam(':hPhone', $hPhone);
                $stmt->bindParam(':cPhone', $cPhone);
                $stmt->bindParam(':pEmail', $pEmail);
                $stmt->bindParam(':aEmail', $aEmail);
                $stmt->bindParam(':inputAddress', $inputAddress);
                $stmt->bindParam(':inputCity', $inputCity);



                if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $conn->commit();
            return true;
        } else {
            $conn->rollback();
            return false;
        }

        }
```

register-functions.php

```
<?php

require_once("db-connect.php");
require_once 'queries.php';


$fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
$lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
$mName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mName");
$tempRace = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "race", FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
$race = (is_array($tempRace)) ? implode(',', $tempRace) : null;
$hEthnicity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hEthnicity");
$gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender");
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "age");
$education = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "education");
$gpa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gpa");
$hPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hPhone");
$cPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cPhone");
$pEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "pEmail");
$aEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "aEmail");
$inputAddress = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "inputAddress");
$inputCity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "inputCity");

switch ($switch) {
    case 'add':
        echo Queries::addStudent($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race, $hEthnicity, $gender,$age,   $education, $gpa, $hPhone, $cPhone, $pEmail, $aEmail, $inputAddress, $inputCity);

        break;

    }
?>
```

main.js

```
$("#Form").submit(function (event) {
        console.log($('#RegId').val());
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/register-functions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"fName": $('#fName').val(), "lName": $('#lName').val(), "mName": $('#mName').val(), "race": $('#race').val(), "hEthnicity": $('#hEthnicity').val(), "gender": $('#gender').val(), "age": $('#age').val(),"education": $('#education').val()   
                , "gpa": $('#gpa').val(), "hPhone": $('#hPhone').val(), "cPhone": $('#cPhone').val(), "pEmail": $('#pEmail').val(),"aEmail": $('#aEmail').val(),
                "inputAddress": $('#inputAddress').val(), "inputCity": $('#inputCity').val(), "switch": "add"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                $('#Form').trigger('reset');


               resultAlert('#FormResult', '#resultFormContent', '<strong>Your data was succefully saved!</strong>', 'alert-success');
            }, error: function () {
                resultAlert('#FormResult', '#resultFormContent', '<strong>Error! Your data was not saved!</strong>', 'alert-danger');
            }
        });
    });
```

email.php

```
<?php


    require_once "../lib/swift_required.php";

    class Form {

        public static function mailer(string $pEmail, string $fName, string $lName) {
            $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.abcd.edu', 25);
            $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('...')
                    ->setFrom(array("form-noreply@xxxx.edu" => "Confirmation Email"))
                    ->setReplyTo(array($pEmail => $fName . " " . $lName))
                    ->setTo(array(""))
                    ->setBody(' 
    Contact Information
    First Name: ' . $fName . '
    Last Name: ' . $lName . '
    Phone: ' . $phone . '
    Email: ' . $pEmail . ' 

    ');
            $result = $mailer->send($message);
            return $result;
        }

    }
```

processEmail.php

```
<?php


ob_start();
require_once 'email.php';

$email = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email')) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email') : null;
$fName = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fName')) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fName') : null;
$lName = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lName')) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lName') : null;


if (Form::mailer($pEmail, $fName, $lName)) {
    echo 
    '<script >
        alert("Thank You for the registration.");
        window.location = "../index.php";
    </script>';
} else {
    echo '
    <script>
        alert("Error, please try submitting again. Error code 1");
        window.history.back();
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You posted a lot of information here but the critical piece you glossed over. "but the following code isn't working". What does that mean?

Comment: "Only the email confirmation doesn't work"

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work"? That does not explain the problem. It only isolates the section. What doesn't work? Does it shut down the server? Does it make squirrel noises on the client machine? Maybe it drops the database? Does it not send an email? Give us some details about **what** the problem is.

Comment: Yes, when the user submits the form, the database gets updated but there is no confirmation email.

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints? You need to figure out what is happening. Does the method to send an email get called? I am a sql server person and this is definitely NOT a sql server issue. This is something in your php code.

Comment: Yeah it's like I have merged two things... the form and email, coz the form gets submitted using the method being called in the main.js and then I added a post method in the form which directs the code to the processEmail. That's the mistake, I guess. I am not sure how to do it in JS.